# javascript regex to validate the input

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to validate my input using javascript Regular Expression.
My valid input should be like this **100*100** or multiple inputs in the same input field like **50*30,90*40 (Separated by comma)**

The input should not be like this  **0*0 or 0 or 50 or 90*90,0*0 or 50*0 or 0*50 **

These are the dimensions of image.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to write a regular expression to validate your input yet? Please post what you've tried

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Only digits? But you have commas and asterisks too

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking and please give it a try first then ask here

Comment: You can [play with this regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XBiRiv/1) and come back with a real question as per [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `^(?!0\*0)(?:\d+\*\d+,?)+$`.

- `^` and `$` ensure that the entire string matches.
- `(?!0\*0)` is a negative look ahead to check that the string is not `0*0`.
- `(?:` and `)` indicates that the contents are a non-capturing group
- `\d+` matches one or more digits (0–9)
- `\*` matches a literal `*` character
- `\d+` matches one or more digits (0–9)
- `,?` optionally match a literal comma
- `+` match one or more of the preceding pattern (`(?:\d+\*\d+,?)`)

Known bug: `50*520*4` matches.

**Edit**: Found a workaround for the bug.

`^(?:(?!0\*0)\d+\*\d+,)*(?:(?!0\*0)\d+\*\d+)$`

**Edit**: You edited your question to make it clear that you do not want to match `50*5,0*0`. This can be achieved by putting the negative lookahead into the repeated match as `^(?:(?!0\*0)\d+\*\d+,?)+$`

**Edit**: You mentioned that you don't want to match `0*[anything]` and `[anything]*0`. Try `^(?:(?!0\*)\d+\*(?!0,)\d+,)*(?:(?!0\*)\d+\*(?!0$)\d+)$`.

Play around with the latest regex with the workaround [on this RegExr demo](https://regexr.com/3t7gk).

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is working fine but there is one bug that it is also accepting like 0*100 or 100*0 expressions

Comment: @Namanjain Please make it clear in your question that you don't want to match those. It's kind of unclear that by "0*0 or 0" you mean "... or 0 times anything.